# Make Exceptions work

Tags: c#, exception

I am not sure how to get the exceptions to work

the program should prompt for the whole number of pounds to convert and the exchange rate. It then should display the equvlient number of follars in a manner similar to the output below.

the first part works here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CurrencyConvertor
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CurrencyConvertor();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CurrencyConvertor()
    {
      int ivalue;
      float exchange;
      float results;
      bool valid;

      Console.WriteLine(" please enter a whole number of pounds");

      do
      {
        try
        {
           ivalue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           Console.WriteLine(" pounds entered : " + ivalue);

           Console.WriteLine("please enter the exchange rate");
           exchange = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           Console.WriteLine(" exchange rate is " + exchange);

           results = ivalue * exchange;
           Console.WriteLine(" £ " + ivalue + " is equivlent to" + " $ {0:N}", results);
           valid = true;
        }
        catch
        {
          Console.WriteLine("unable to convert to integer");
          Console.WriteLine(" Try again- ensure you enter a number");
          valid = false;
        }
      } while (valid == false);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Both inputs should be validated to ensure that the user enters an appropriate data type - the output below illustrates the expected output if the user enters non numerical data.

so it should displays

```
please enter an integer
try again - ensure you enter an integer
12
pounds entered 12
please enter an exchange rate 
asd
unable to convert to a number 
try again - ensure you enter a number
1.56
exchange rate is 1:56
£12.00 is equivalent to $18.72
```

I cant seem to get it to display the error message for the exchange rate to say " unable to convert to a number "

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Which line seems to fail?

Comment: please get rid of all that empty lines

Comment: there should be another exception in there so it should display   'console.writelinne("unable to conver to a number")' @YuvalItzchakov not sure where it goes ?

Comment: You are using exceptions in entirely the wrong way, you should be using `int.TryParse` to validate the number, not catching the exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some flaws in your code:

- you should prefer `int.TryParse` instead of `Parse`. An `Exception` should be an unexpected behavior, where you have to react in some way. A userinput is not unexpected, you know there's a chance that the use inputs invalid data which you can/have to validate.
- When you use exceptions, you should not catch all exceptions at once, but some type of exception where you know how to react. `int.Parse` itself throws three kind of exceptions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx), you can get some other ones from the system itself. Your code should catch `FormatException` instead of a catch-all.
- anyway, if you just want to fix your code, you can solve your problem with using two seperate `try .. catch` blocks with seperated error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are there to catch the exceptional - the things you don't expect to happen but might

You should be using `TryParse` methods instead

```
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ivalue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thats not a number, try again");
}
```